# The constructor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions) is undefined

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using Selenium 3.5.3 and following is my code.

I am trying to use Firefox options in the constructor as in
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions-

```
FirefoxOptions options=new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(profile);
driver =new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I am getting an error in instantiating the Firefox driver:

> The constructor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions) is undefined

How can I solve this?

Firefox version 55.0.3 64 bit
Geckodriver v0.18.0

Comment: What is the version of firefox u use, are u use geckdriver

Comment: @iamsankalp89 i have added the version details

Comment: I am able to run it selenium jar 3.5

Comment: What is your Selenium version?

Comment: @Guy Selenium 3.5.3

Comment: If you are using 3.5.3 then there should be option of the FirefoxOptions  constructor

Comment: @iamsankalp89 not yet, i will clean my maven and try again,

Comment: @iamsankalp89 can you show me your imports

Comment: @deepakguna I updated my answer with Imports

Comment: u got it? try this

Comment: @iamsankalp89 issue resolved with mvn clean install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153760/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-deepakguna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to older selenium version coexisted. mvn clean install resolved the issue.

Comment: How make mvn clean install in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class FirefoxOptionsDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile profile =new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\sys\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ejtrne37.QAProfile"));
FirefoxOptions option=new FirefoxOptions();
option.setProfile(profile);
// Initialize Firefox driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);
//Maximize browser window
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//Go to URL which you want to navigate
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
//Set  timeout  for 5 seconds so that the page may load properly within that time
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//close firefox browser
driver.close();
}
}
```

This is the image for your reference:

[image: FirefoxOptions Constructor]

Comment: If you look at my question ,This statement "new FirefoxDriver(option)"  gets the error - The constructor FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions) is undefined

Comment: are u import import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

Comment: @deepak u do it?

Comment: yes i have it in my import , but still not seeing the FirefoxDriver constructor which takes FirefoxOptions as argument

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to different causes.

The common cause is a **misaligned version** of your firefox browser and/or **gecko driver and/or selenium library**.

I solved this problem **upgrading** gecko driver and selenium library to the latest version.

In my case, mvn clean install does not resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since an upgrade to current available release versions is not a doable action by many since it is not acceptable to their teams due to the impact - so they need a working fix for current in use version itself hence my answer -
I may be answering it a lot late but my solution is a workable one for this problem and I can even explain why it is workable and why above one is not workable as asked in your query -
For older selenium and gecko driver versions, the above suggested method i.e. Options class utilization used to work from Selenium 3.5 and upwards (officially) but for versions lower than 3.5 - the options class was not available, so the above suggested method does not work.
I backtracked and found that even in the most widespread popular Selenium version 3.14(which I ended up using for project specific needs, even though the current stable release is at Selenium 4.5 :D) the options class and above suggested method does not work.
So the alternative is just to replace the import of options class and utilization of any of its methods.
In my code I just used direct paths for geckodriver and firefox exe paths and then instantiated the FirefoxDriver class object via WebDriver interface and the constructor is undefined error stops troubling as it is we are not passing any argument in constructor as expected by Eclipse JVM:
Here are my exact lines of code to solve this -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium Projects\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" );
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Rest of the code remains as is originally.
The above method of options class utilization or multiple arguments in constructor are supported only after Selenium 3.6. If you use latest selenium and geckodriver, then I dont think you will run in above problem at all as I was able to see it working in the latest versions.
But sometimes we can't just upgrade to our wishes, and we need a fix in the current used versions itself, hence this solution has been suggested by me.